# Example of $\mu_n$ absolutely continuous to Lebesgue but $\mu$ is not

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Give an example of a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra  converging in weak topology to a probability measure $\mu$ such that each $\mu_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, but $\mu$ is not.

I thought of using $\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ once it would converge to $\delta_0$ which implies $\delta_0{0}=1$. But then each $\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ is not absolutely continuous to Lebesgue once $\lambda(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n$.
I do not know a lot of probability to pick up any more examples.

**Question**:

Which could be an example of a probability measure with the aforementioned conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\mu_n$ to be the uniform distribution on $[0,1/n]$. Then each $\mu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue's measure, but the sequence converges weakly to $\delta_0$ which is not.

This is easily seen by the fact that the distribution function of $\mu_n$ converges to $1_{[0,\infty)}$ (the distribution function of $\delta_0$) in all of its continuity points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you show why the uniform distribution is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue?

Comment: The measure $\mu_n$ has (by definition) the Lebesgue density $\phi_n:=n\cdot 1_{[0,1/n]}$. Hence any set with $\lambda(B)=0$ has $\mu_n(B)=\int_B \phi_nd\lambda=0$. The same argument shows that for any two probability measures $\mu,\nu$ such that $\mu$ has a density with respect to $\nu$, we automatically have $\mu\ŀl\nu$. In fact, the converse is also true (thanks to the Radon-Nikodym theorem).

Comment: Could you add some steps for the integral computation, please?

Comment: To calculate it straight forward in this context, we have

$$0\le \int_B \phi_nd\lambda \le \int_B \sup_{x\in B}\phi_n(x) d\lambda \le \int_B n d\lambda= n\lambda(B)=0$$

However, it is true in general that the integral of any function over a set of measure zero will vanish. This is because if the whole space on which a measure $\mu$ is defined is denoted by $\Omega$, the notation $\int_B fd\mu$ is just short for $\int_\Omega 1_B f d\mu$. So if $\mu(B)=0$, the function $1_B f$ vanishes $\mu$-almost everywhere (no matter what $f$ does) and hence its integral is zero.

Comment: How can $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int \phi_n d\lambda=\int\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_nd\lambda\neq \delta_0$? I do not know what to do to get $\delta_0$

Comment: I think you are confusing some things. Do you want to check weak convergence directly by its definition? This is also possible by basic analysis.

Comment: I have been spending a lot of time on this question. I would appreciate if you could show me.

Comment: For any continuous function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta>0$ such that

$$ |f(x)-f(0)|\le \epsilon \quad \text{for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $|x|<\delta$.}$$

Then for $n \ge \lfloor1/\delta\rfloor$ we have

$$ |\int fd\mu_n-\int fd\delta_0|\le \int |f-f(0)|d\mu_n= n \int_0^{1/n}|f(x)-f(0)|dx\le n \lambda([0,1/n])\epsilon=\epsilon,$$

and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have shown that $\int fd\mu_n$ converges to $\int fd\delta_0$.

Comment: However, as I said in my original answer, checking pointwise convergence of the distribution functions (in all of the continuity points of the distribution function of the limit) is easier. Many textbooks dealing only with real-valued random variables use this as the definition of weak convergence.